# $p$ and $\neg\,q$ implies not $q$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I need help showing the equivalence of $(p \wedge \neg q) \implies ¬q$. I know I have to use the equation $p \implies q = \neg\,p \lor q$, but I don't know how to begin changing the propositions around. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are talking about equivalence, but I do not see any. Do you mean that the term is always true, that it is a tautology?

Comment: Yes, but I have to show it is a tautology by establishing a sequence of equivalences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{lcl}(p \wedge \neg q)\rightarrow \neg q & \Leftrightarrow & \neg (p\wedge \neg q) \vee \neg q \\ & \Leftrightarrow & \neg[(p\wedge \neg q)\wedge q] \\ &\Leftrightarrow & \neg [p\wedge (\neg q\wedge q)] \\ & \Leftrightarrow & \neg (p\wedge 0) \\ & \Leftrightarrow & \neg 0 \\ &\Leftrightarrow & 1 \end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$A\implies B \equiv \neg A \lor B$$

If you apply this to your expression, you get

$$\neg(p\land \neg q)\lor \neg q$$

Now, use DeMorgan's law $\neg(A\lor B)\equiv \neg A\land \neg B$ and use the distributivity of $\land$ and $\lor$, i.e.

$$A\lor(B\land C)\equiv (A\lor B)\land (A\lor C)$$
What do you get?

Comment: The OP already stated that, in their question.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to use the equivalence

$$(A\implies B)\iff (\lnot B\implies \lnot A) $$